# Box node js Api (view-box) not fetching documents

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, box

I am trying to integrate box view node js API for box document view.
I have created a node js server. And fetched document and created session and all is working file.
Now when I uploaded some document manually on box.com so it do not fetching documented uploaded manually, It is only showing the list of document which are uploaded programmatically using box view node js API.
Please some one help on this.

Thanks for help in advance.
Sunny K.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I talked to support of box. They told me that files uploaded using box view api and file uploaded from website both are not interconnected. Both are on different places and there is no connection between them.
For using box view api I need to develop some more code for upload document from my own website. And I can fetch these documents only using box view api.
For accessing files uploaded from website. we need to develop application with box content api and box content api do not have any PHP or Node js api right now.